# Sending JSON from an asp.net site to Python Script

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, visual-studio

I'd like to preface this by saying that I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed at a summer internship, it's a lot of new technologies and concepts I've never used before and finding good resources to explain these things and not just regurgitate situational tutorials are very scarce. Particularly I'd like to talk about ASP.NET.

What I currently have is a simple webpage made using ASP.NET in visual studio. My general task is to access a database, get the info from the database, turn the data into JSON, and send that data to a python script which will then parse the JSON and do stuff with it, etc.

I am able to get as far as making the JSON object. I can get the user to download the json object as a file, but what I really want to do is just pass it through the network by accessing my web site from the python script using `urllib2`. This is where I have become completely lost. There are so many terms I've never heard of before, things like services, web APIs, controllers, routing and all these things I've spent hours digging around in and following basic tutorials but still cannot find a firm grasp on the *concepts* let alone how to accomplish it in a practical manner.

To be completely clear here are my goals:

1. Send 5 parameters using`urllib2` in python to my asp.net site
2. use these parameters to query the database and get a json object (**COMPLETE**)
3. return the json to the python script

I have no idea how to set up a "service" or how to even go about doing so. I know that I have to attach it to my website somehow but I'm not sure. Any suggestions or good resources would be much appreciated. I'm just looking for some direction and advice on how to go about accomplishing #1 and #3 on my list.

Thank you for taking the time to read through my post!

Answer (score 0):

For part one you could do this:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://mysite.io?paramOne=ValueOne/')
```

Now the response object will have your JSON so you can do this:

```
json = response.read()
```

*urllib2 has a nice way of preparing URL parameters which you might want* to look into.